# How to implement overlap-checking memcpy in C?

Tags: c, unix, pointers, memory-management

This is a learning exercise. I'm attempting to augment memcpy by notifying the user if the copy operation will pass or fail before it begins. My biggest question is the following. If I allocate two char arrays of 100 bytes each, and have two pointers that reference each array, how do I know which direction I am copying? If I copy everything from the first array to the second how do I ensure that the user will not be overwriting the original array?

My current solution compares the distance of the pointers from the size of the destination array. If the size between is smaller than I say an overwrite will occur. But what if its copying in the other direction? I'm just kind of confused.

```
int memcpy2(void *target, void *source, size_t nbytes) {
    char * ptr1 = (char *)target;
    char * ptr2 = (char *)source;


    int i, val;

    val = abs(ptr1 - ptr2);
    printf("%d, %d\n", val, nbytes + 0);
    if (val > nbytes) {
        for (i = 0; i < val; i++){
            ptr1[i] = ptr2[i];
        }
        return 0;  /*success */
    }
    return -1; /* error */
}



int main(int argc, char **argv){

  char src [100] = "Copy this string to dst1";
  char dst [20];
  int p;
  p = memcpy2(dst, src, sizeof(dst));

    if (p == 0)
        printf("The element\n'%s'\nwas copied to \n'%s'\nSuccesfully\n", src, dst);
    else
        printf("There was an error!!\n\nWhile attempting to copy the elements:\n '%s'\nto\n'%s', \n Memory was overlapping", src, dst);
    return 0;


}
```

Comment: `memcpy` isn't guaranteed to work for overlapping regions, but `memmove` is. Maybe you want to implement `memmove` semantics instead?

Comment: This is what memmove is for. Find some source for that.

Comment: where do you find the source code of C functions? I see their headers in /usr/include/...

Comment: Try searching for the glibc or ulibc source code.

Comment: memcpy() doesn't succeed or fail in the normal sense. It just copies the data, which might cause a fault/exception if it reads outside the source array or writes outside the destination array, and it might also read or write outside one of those arrays without causing any fault/exception and just silently corrupting data. When I say "memcpy does this" I'm not talking just about the implementation of the C stdlib memcpy, but about any function with the same signature -- it doesn't have enough information to do otherwise.

Comment: Note the people talking about memmove() instead of memcpy(): if your definition of "succeed" is "assuming the buffers are big enough but may be overlapping, copy the data from source to dst without tripping over *yourself* while copying" -- that is indeed what memmove() does, but it's always possible. If the buffers don't overlap it's easy, if the source is overlapping the end of the destination then you just copy byte by byte from the beginning; if the source is overlapping the beginning of the destination then you just copy byte by byte from the end. Which is what memmove() does.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only *portable* way to determine if two memory ranges overlap is:

```
int overlap_p(void *a, void *b, size_t n)
{
    char *x = a, *y =  b;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) if (x+i==y || y+i==x) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

This is because comparison of pointers with the relational operators is undefined unless they point into the same array. In reality, the comparison does work on most real-world implementations, so you could do something like:

```
int overlap_p(void *a, void *b, size_t n)
{
    char *x = a, *y =  b;
    return (x<=y && x+n>y) || (y<=x && y+n>x);
}
```

I hope I got that logic right; you should check it. You can simplify it even more if you want to assume you can take differences of arbitrary pointers.

Comment: @R - should the second code example use `x` and `y` rather than `a` and `b`?

Comment: You could reduce the nominal arithmetic by adding `char *z = b+n-1;` and testing `x+i == y || x+i == z`, so a second addition for `y+i` in each iteration is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to check is the position in memory of the source relatively to the destination:

If the source is ahead of the destination (ie. source < destination), then you should start from the end. If the source is after, you start from the beginning. If they are equal, you don't have to do anything (trivial case).

Here are some crude ASCII drawings to visualize the problem.

```
|_;_;_;_;_;_|          (source)
      |_;_;_;_;_;_|    (destination)
            >-----^    start from the end to shift the values to the right

      |_;_;_;_;_;_|    (source)
|_;_;_;_;_;_|          (destination)
^-----<                 start from the beginning to shift the values to the left
```

Following a very accurate comment below, I should add that you can use the difference of the pointers (destination - source), but to be on the safe side cast those pointers to char * beforehand.

In your current setting, I don't think that you can check if the operation will fail. Your memcpy prototype prevents you from doing any form of checking for that, and with the rule given above for deciding how to copy, the operation will succeed (outside of any other considerations, like prior memory corruption or invalid pointers).

Comment: One additional situation is `source` and `destination` pointing to different objects, in which case `source < destination` invokes undefined behavior. Most compilers will do what you want with `(uintptr_t)source < (uintptr_t)destination`.

Comment: Indeed, the pointers are void *. Instead of comparing, we could compute the difference as the OP did originally.

Comment: In the original example, the arrays `src` and `dst` are two distinct objects. They cannot overlap by virtue of being distinct objects, but this means that `ptr1 - ptr2` in the original example is undefined, as would be the `ptr1 < ptr2` that you suggest to write. See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf 6.5.8:5, 6.5.6:9

Comment: Yeah, the standard doesn't define void pointer substractions. GCC emits a simple warning in pedantic mode though.

Comment: Not only that, but “When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object”. Undefined behavior is bad even when your compiler does not have a warning for it. See http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213 and http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_14.html (short version: your compiler may take advantage of undefined behaviors in your program, undefined behaviors it does NOT warn for, to do very strange, unexpected things. Do not use undefined behavior)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that "attempting to augment memcpy by notifying the user if the copy operation will pass or fail before it begins." is a well-formed notion.

First, memcpy() doesn't succeed or fail in the normal sense. It just copies the data, which might cause a fault/exception if it reads outside the source array or writes outside the destination array, and it might also read or write outside one of those arrays without causing any fault/exception and just silently corrupting data. When I say "memcpy does this" I'm not talking just about the implementation of the C stdlib memcpy, but about any function with the same signature -- it doesn't have enough information to do otherwise.

Second, if your definition of "succeed" is "assuming the buffers are big enough but may be overlapping, copy the data from source to dst without tripping over yourself while copying" -- that is indeed what memmove() does, and it's always possible. Again, there's no "return failure" case. If the buffers don't overlap it's easy, if the source is overlapping the end of the destination then you just copy byte by byte from the beginning; if the source is overlapping the beginning of the destination then you just copy byte by byte from the end. Which is what memmove() does.

Third, when writing this kind of code, you have to be very careful about overflow cases for your pointer arithmetic (including addition, subtraction, and array indexing). In `val = abs(ptr1 - ptr2)`, `ptr1 - ptr2` could be a very large number, and it will be unsigned, so `abs()` won't do anything to it, and `int` is the wrong type to store that in. Just so you know.

Comment: *"I don't believe that 'attempting to augment memcpy by notifying the user if the copy operation will pass or fail before it begins' is a well-formed notion."* - that's what we call [bikeshedding](http://bikeshed.com/), and its probably better left as a comment. Overlapping buffers and use of `memcpy` causes problems in practice. See, for example, LWN.net's [On Breaking Things](https://lwn.net/Articles/416821/) and [Glibc Change Exposing bugs](https://lwn.net/Articles/414467/); and the discussion of Adobe's Flash.