# Safely checking for overlapping memory regions

Tags: c

I'm trying to further my knowledge and experience in C, so I'm writing some small utilities.

I'm copying memory, and according to the man page for `memcpy(3)`:

> **NOTES**
>
> Failure to observe the requirement that the memory areas do not overlap  has  been
> the  source  of real bugs.  (POSIX and the C standards are explicit that employing
> memcpy() with overlapping areas produces undefined behavior.)   Most  notably,  in
> glibc  2.13  a  performance  optimization of memcpy() on some platforms (including
> x86-64) included changing the order in which bytes were copied from src to dest.

Clearly, overlapping memory regions passed to `memcpy(3)` can [cause a lot of problems](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=638477).

I'm trying to write a safe wrapper as part of learning C to make sure that these memory regions don't overlap:

```c
int safe_memcpy(void *dest, void *src, size_t length);
```

The logic I'm trying to implement is:

- Check both the source and destination pointers for `NULL`.
- Establish the pointer "range" for both source and dest with the length parameter.
- Determine if the source range intersects with the destination range, and vice versa.

My implementation so far:

```c
#define SAFE_MEMCPY_ERR_NULL 1
#define SAFE_MEMCPY_ERR_SRC_OVERLAP 2
#define SAFE_MEMCPY_ERR_DEST_OVERLAP 3

int safe_memcpy(void *dest, void *src, size_t length) {
    if (src == NULL || dest == NULL) {
        return SAFE_MEMCPY_ERR_NULL;
    }

    void *dest_end = &dest[length - 1];
    void *src_end = &src[length - 1];

    if ((&src >= &dest && &src <= &dest_end) ||
            (&src_end >= &dest && &src_end <= &dest_end)) {
        // the start of src falls within dest..dest_end OR
        // the end of src falls within dest..dest_end
        return SAFE_MEMCPY_ERR_SRC_OVERLAP;
    }

    if ((&dest >= &src && &dest <= &src_end) ||
            (&dest_end >= &src && &dest_end <= &src_end)) {
        // the start of dest falls within src..src_end
        // the end of dest falls within src..src_end
        return SAFE_MEMCPY_ERR_DEST_OVERLAP;
    }

    // do the thing
    memcpy(dest, src, length);

    return 0;
}
```

There's probably a better way to do errors, but this is what I've got for now.

I'm pretty sure I'm triggering some undefined behavior in this code, as I'm hitting `SAFE_MEMCPY_ERR_DEST_OVERLAP` on memory regions that do not overlap. When I examine the state using a debugger, I see (for instance) the following values:

- `src`: `0x7ffc0b75c5fb`
- `src_end`: `0x7ffc0b75c617`
- `dest`: `0x1d05420`
- `dest_end`: `0x1d0543c`

Clearly, *these addresses do not even remotely overlap*, hence why I'm thinking I'm triggering UB, and compiler warnings indicate as such:

```
piper.c:68:27: warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer
     void *dest_end = &dest[length - 1];
```

[It seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15468441/dereference-void-pointer) that I need to cast the pointers as a different type, but I'm not sure which type to use: the memory is untyped so should I use a `char *` to "look at" the memory as bytes? If so, should I cast everything as a `char *`? Should I instead use `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t`?

Given two pointers and a length for each of them, how can I safely check if these regions overlap one another?

Answer (score 4):

In the first place, a conforming program cannot perform pointer arithmetic on a pointer of type `void *`, nor (relatedly) apply the indexing operator to it, not even with index `0`.  `void` is an *incomplete type*, and unique among those in that it cannot be completed.  The most relevant implication of that is that that type does not convey any information about the size of the thing to which it points, and pointer arithmetic is defined in terms of the pointed-to object.

So yes, expressions such as your `&dest[length - 1]` have undefined behavior with respect to the C standard.  Some implementations provide extensions affecting that, and others reject such code at compile time.  In principle, an implementation could accept the code and do something bizarre with it, but that's relatively unlikely.

In the second place, you propose to

> write a safe wrapper as part of learning C to make sure that these memory regions don't overlap

, but there is no conforming way to do that for general pointers.  Pointer comparisons and pointer differences are defined only for pointers into the same array (or to one element past the end of the array), where a pointer to a scalar is considered in that regard as a pointer to the first element of dimension-1 array.

Converting to a different pointer type, perhaps `char *`, would resolve the pointer arithmetic issue, but not, in the general case, the pointer comparability issue.  It might get exactly the behavior you want out of some implementations, reliably even, but it is not a conforming approach to the problem, and the ensuing undefined behavior might produce genuine bugs in other implementations.

Relatively often, you can know statically that pointers do not point to overlapping regions.  In particular, if one pointer in question is a pointer to an in-scope local variable or to a block of memory allocated by the current function, then you can usually be sure whether there is an overlap.  For cases where you do not know, or where you know that there definitely is overlap, the correct approach is to use `memmove()` instead of `memcpy()`.

Comment: I had read [this article](https://www.ralfj.de/blog/2018/07/24/pointers-and-bytes.html) previously on pointers, and this seems to be the answer to the underlying question: "pointers are neither simple nor (just) integers." However, since I'm still just kind of learning the ropes of C, it didn't immediately click, but makes sense with the erasure of `void *`.

Answer (score 3):

This "safe" `memcpy` is not safe as well as it does not copy anything when programmes expects it. Use `memmove` to be safe

You should not use `&src` and `&dest` as it is not beginning of the data or buffer but the address of the parameter `src` and `dest` itself.

Same is with `srcend` and `destend`

Comment: Re: "does not copy:" yes, it's a different API, not a drop-in replacement, a different, fallible return signature. As for using `&src`/`&dest`, I'm trying to compare the addresses themselves to check for overlap, should I not be using the address operator?

Comment: As I wrote `&src` is not giving you the beginning of the sourcerc buffer only the address of `src` parameter (variable). You should just use `src` and dest. Or if you have problem to understand it use `&src[0]` ....

Answer (score 2):

> Given two pointers and a length for each of them, how can I safely check if these regions overlap one another?

`<`, `<=`, `>=`, `>` are not defined when 2 pointers are not related to the same object.

A tedious approach checks the endpoints of one against all the other's elements and takes advantage that the length of the source and destination are the same.

```
int safe_memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t length) {
  if (length > 0) {
    unsigned char *d = dest;
    const unsigned char *s = src;
    const unsigned char *s_last = s + length - 1;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      if (s == &d[i]) return 1; // not safe
      if (s_last == &d[i]) return 1; // not safe
    }

    memcpy(dest, src, length);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

If the buffer lengths differ, check the shorter one's endpoints against the addresses of the longer one's elements.

---

> should I cast everything as a `char *`

Use `unsigned char *`.
`mem...()`, `str...()` behave as if each array element was `unsigned char`.

> For all functions in this subclause, each character shall be interpreted as if it had the type `unsigned char` (and therefore every possible object representation is valid and has a different value). C17dr § 7.24.1 3

With rare non-2's complement, `unsigned char` is important to avoid *signed* `char` traps and maintain -0, +0 distinctiveness.  Strings only stop on +0.

With functions like `int strcmp/memcmp()`, `unsigned char` that use integer math, it is important when comparing elements outside the range of `[0...CHAR_MAX]` to return the correctly signed result.

---

Even if `void *` indexing was allowed, `void *dest_end = &dest[length - 1];` is very bad when `length == 0` as that is like `&dest[SIZE_MAX];`

---

`&src >= &dest` s/b `src >= dest` for even a chance at working.

The addresses of `src, dest` are irrelevant to the copy, only their values are important.

I suspect this errant code leads to UB in OP's other code.

---

> Should I instead use `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t`?

Note that `(u)intptr_t` are optional types - they might not exist in a conforming compiler.

Even when the types exist, math on the pointers is not defined to be related to math on the integer values.

---

> Clearly, these addresses do not even remotely overlap, hence why I'm thinking I'm triggering UB,

"Clearly" if ones *assumes* a liner mapping addresses to integers, something not specified in C.

Answer (score 1):

> The memory is untyped so should I use a char * to "look at" the memory as bytes? If so, should I cast everything as a char *?

Use `unsigned char*` if you need to dereference the data, or just `char*` when you want to increment/decrement the pointer value by count of bytes.

[It's common](https://chromium.googlesource.com/native_client/nacl-newlib/+/da717459e4577690dfce366a17202df8d01281ce/newlib/libc/string/memcpy.c#68) to do:

```
void a_function_that_takes_void(void *x, void *y) {
    char *a = x;
    char *b = y;
    /* uses a and b throughout here */
}
```

> If so, should I cast everything as a char *?

Yes. It's also common to do:

```
 void_pointer = (char*)void_pointer + 1;
```

> Should I instead use intptr_t or uintptr_t?

You could, but that would be the same as using `char*`, except for a `char*` to `intptr_t` conversion.

> how can I safely check if these regions overlap one another?

It's good to do some research. [how to implement overlap-checking memcpy in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095488/how-to-implement-overlap-checking-memcpy-in-c)

Comment: it is funny because almost all strict portability fanatics use `gcc` which is not conforming compiler of C actually implementing own dialect of C. gcc extension allows void pointer arithmetic.

Comment: *Should I instead use intptr_t or uintptr_t?*  **NO**. That is, converting the pointers to integers is allowed, and you have a wider range of arithmetic options with the results, but their relationship to each other and to the specified length is not guaranteed to make it possible to determine whether your regions overlap.

Comment: @P__J__ (The standard says, that conforming implementation may have extensions, and arithmetic on `void*` is _undefined_ behavior, which means the standard poses no requirements on the behavior, which means a conforming compiler may have a custom behavior for arithmetic on `void*` pointer required from somewhere else, for example from gcc documentation. It's an extension, not a sign of non-conformity)

Comment: @KamilCuk it is not an UB in gcc because it is not conforming compiler. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html  As I wrote the most common use compiler is not conforming.

Comment: Defining behavior for pointer arithmetic with type `void *` does not make GCC non-conforming.  Failing to emit a diagnostic about such operations *does*, however, because such operations violate a language constraint.  GCC's `-pedantic` option takes care of most, if not all, of its conformance issues surrounding required diagnostics.

Comment: Using `unsigned char *` has an advantage over `char *` on those all but forgotten non-2's complement machines - no traps.