# Mimicking memmove's behaviour

Tags: c, string, memmove

I am attempting to create a function with a similar work to memmove. I found in the man that the copying is done by including a transitionnal array to where bytes are copied first , which should not overlap with dest, then copied to destination. This the code I attempted to make (including the necessary headers):

```
void    *ft_memmove(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n)
{
    unsigned char p[n];
    unsigned char *p2;
    const unsigned char *p3;
    size_t i;

    p2 = dest;
    p3 = src;
    i = 0;
    while (i < n)
        *(p + i++) = *(p3++);
    while (n--)
        *(p2++) = *(p++);
    return (dest);
}
```

I believe the problem is related to assigning the const void array's elements to p while it is a constant or something similar. Should I use malloc or is there another possible way? Or my uderstanding of how memmove actually wroks is wrong because I found other definitions somewhere else.

I ran the previous code on this main:

```
int main()
{
    char s1[] = "holala";
    char s2[] = "dongo";

    ft_memmove(s1, s2, sizeof(s2));
    printf("%p,\n", s1);
}
```

It should've shown "donga", instead I get this error:

```
ft_memmove.c:17:22: error: lvalue required as increment operand
   17 |         *(p2++) = *(p++);
```

Comment: The man page says that *"copying takes place **as though** the bytes in src are first copied into a temporary array"*, but that isn't literally what is happening, it's likely never the case as it would just be 2x slower. All you need to do to implement `memmove` is check whether there is overlap and in such case perform the copy in reverse.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Checking for overlap is not easy, since it's not portable to use `<` or `>` between pointers to different arrays. The only portable way is a nested loop looking that checks whether there are any elements in the two arrays whose addresses are `==`.

Comment: OT: OP's test case could simply use `memcpy()`... To test `memmove()`, use only one array...

Comment: PS: "_It should've shown 'donga'_"... Not with the format specifier `%p`...

Comment: @Barmar "nested loop"? Loop, yes, but sufficient to test only if the first or last byte's address of one array falls within the range of the other.... (loop testing `==`) No?

Comment: @Barmar then I suppose [musl](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/string/memmove.c#n15), [glibc](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/string/memmove.c#L51), [bionic](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/75ef63d/libc/upstream-openbsd/lib/libc/string/bcopy.c#76) and [uClibc](https://elixir.bootlin.com/uclibc-ng/latest/source/libc/string/generic/memmove.c#L226) are all doing it wrong :')

Comment: Note that even using `%s` you will still see `dongo` as output because you are also copying the string terminator to `s1`.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli C runtime libraries generally don't try to limit themselves to portable code.

Comment: @Fe2O3 Yeah, I had a feeling it was a little easier. But it's still O(n)

Comment: @Barmar: [You do not need a nested loop.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095488/how-to-implement-overlap-checking-memcpy-in-c)

Comment: @EricPostpischil I already admitted that. You just need a single loop that checks the  start and end pointers, as Fe2O3 said.

Comment: This isn't rocket science: allocate a buffer and make two calls to memcpy, done. Everything else is nonsense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p` is an array, not a pointer, so you can't increment it. Use different variables for the temporary array and the pointer, so you can increment the pointer.

```
void    *ft_memmove(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n)
{
    unsigned char temp[n];
    unsigned char *p = temp;
    unsigned char *p2;
    const unsigned char *p3;

    p2 = dest;
    p3 = src;
    for (sizt_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        *(p++) = *(p3++);
    }
    p = temp;
    while (n--) {
        *(p2++) = *(p++);
    }
    return (dest);
}
```

Or you could do it like the way you assigned to `p` in the first loop, using `*(p2++) = *(p + i++)`

Comment: I see problems when `n` is big, which would not be un-typical for `memmove()`. Is a temporary array really necessary? Wouldn't want a .... Stack Overflow.

Comment: There are ways to do this without the temporary array, but you need to figure out how the two arrays overlap. If the source overlaps the beginning of the dest, copy the bytes from the end down. If it overlaps the end, copy from the beginning up. But as mentioned in the comments, determining this is O(n) in portable code.

Comment: You could certainly use `malloc()` to avoid the stack overflow for large N.

Comment: I get you about comparing pointers from different arrays being undefined. You'll struggle to find an implementation where that doesn't work though, I'd bet. I think OP wants a practical solution. You could add the "technically UB but practical" to your answer.

Comment: Why will the stack overflow occur if there is a large N?

Comment: This is a pedagogical exercise, not something you'd actually write, since you'd just use `memmove()`. @pmacfarlane

Comment: @SamiWalid Because most systems have a relatively small limit on the size of stack frames. Creating large local variables overflows this.

Comment: @SamiWalid See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15283546/segmentation-fault-while-creating-large-arrays-in-c

Comment: @Barmar The OP's question is basically "how do I write `memmove()`". Not sure saying "call `memmove()`" is the answer they seek.

Comment: @pmacfarlane Of course. But in real life you wouldn't do this at all, so what's "practical" is irrelevant. I view this as "how would I write memmove myself portably?", not "how would I do it if I were writing a libc?"

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to mimic `memmove()` without a temporary array, but it is not straightforward and there is a lesson to be learned from that, so let us have a try.

With `memmove()`, the source(S) and destination(D) areas may overlap. There are 4 possibilities:

1. S and D are completely disjoint
2. S and D are identical
3. D overlaps the lower part of S
4. D overlaps the higher part of S

If bytes are copied one by one from the beginning of S, then the only problematic case is "4", where bytes have to be copied in reverse order:

```
void *ft_memmove(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n)
{
    unsigned char * D = dest;
    const unsigned char * S = src;
    if(is_within_and_not_equal(D, S, n))
    { // Reverse order
        D += n-1;
        S += n-1;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            *(D--) = *(S--);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            *(D++) = *(S++);
        }
    }
    return dest;
}
```

It may be chosen to extend this by identifying cases "1" (use `memcpy`) and "2" (do nothing).

Notice the helper function `is_within_and_not_equal(D, S, n)`. This must check if `D` is within the array `S` of `n` elements, i.e. if `D > S && D < S + n`. However, the result of that comparison is unspecified by the standard unless `D` points into the same area as `S`. Therefore, a portable implementation would need to be:

```
    #include<stdbool.h>

    bool is_within_and_not_equal(const unsigned char *D, const unsigned char *S, size_t n)
    {
        for(size_t i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            if(D == S+i) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

A major point in having the standard library functions is that, behind the scene, they may be implemented in a non-portable way taking advantage of additional prerequisites than those specified in the C Standard.

No sane standard library implementation would use something like the above implementation of `is_within_and_not_equal()`, but when we try to implement standard library functions using only the standard language assumptions, it may not be possible to implement these functions efficiently or implement them at all.

Comment: In the reverse version, `D` and `S` end up pointing to the bytes before `dest` and `src`, so `S` could end up as an invalid pointer value. So it would be safer to use `D += n;` `S += n;` and `*(--D) = *(--S);` (although the parentheses are not necessary of course).